# How do I set histogram axis to always be an integer?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using a bit of code to run and generate reports with Python. This code takes information from an online survey tool and runs basic statistics on the data then generates a word document based on the results. I am creating a number of graphs along the way. I have the following function to help me build some of the histograms.

```
def histogram_by(df, df_column, sort_by, height):
    """
    df = location of the data
    df_column = column in the data frame with the required data
    sort_by = the column used to catagorize the data
    height = the calculated height of the subplots, changes depending on number of plots
    """
    f, ax = generate_subplots(df[sort_by].nunique(), height)
    df[df_column].hist(
        ax=ax,
        by=df[sort_by],
        xrot=360,
        bins=np.linspace(1, 5, 9))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('plt.png')
```

[image: This is the output if i have enough data for the Y-Axis to force integers]

[image: Data without forced integers]

So in the first picture it shows what the graphs looks like when there is enough data to force integers. This happens in most cases.

In the second picture there is not enough data to force the Y-Axis to make integers, so it creates floats. It also appears that the graphs in this version are a bit wider in comparison to the 'correct' output. Any ideas?

The amount of data changes based on how many people answered the surveys. Is there any way to force the Y-Axis to use integers instead of defaulting to floats?

Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a minimal example of the issue.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,1.7))

data = np.random.randint(1,9, size=52)
ax.hist(data, bins=np.arange(0,9)+0.5, ec="k")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, you can get rid of the decimals on the y axis by telling the default `AutoLocator` to use only integers

```
ax.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You call the numpy array of axes `ax`. You need to use a single axes for the use of `locator_params`. So something like `for singleax in ax.flat: singleax.locator_params...`

Comment: I had to call locator_params on my plt object instead of my ax object due to the nature of my function. Thanks again!

Comment: If you call `plt.locator_params` it would only apply to one of the axes. In a function like the one you have, best don't use `pyplot` commands at all, i.e. `f.savefig` instead of `plt.savefig`.